# Animated gifs causing input flicker in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, gif, animated

The Cursor in an input flickers with IE7 when the page has an animated gif on it.

Take away the gif, and the problem goes away.

Edit (again):
What I really need is somebody who knows the answer to a bizarre ie bug.

I'm a 10 year experienced web app developer.  Trust me, I know how to debug -- for instance, knowing for a fact that the animated gif is the reason for the screen draw is the result of a successful debug.  Fixing that is another matter.

Edit (again, again), using my gif, and the code from answer three below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #img {
                position: absolute;
            }
            #dv {
                background-color: transparent;
                border: 1px solid Black;
                height: 450px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 600px;
            }
            #frm {
                left: 170px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.johnherr.net/skeleton.gif" id="img">
        <div id="dv">
        </div>
        <form id="frm">
            <input type="text">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give some HTML please, also could you please tell the size of the gif (dimensions and filesize)

Comment: The first step in debugging a problem like this is to remove all the junk surrounding it.  If during this process it starts working, you're done.  If not, you've made the problem ias simple as possible, which is your best bet as far as debugging goes, even if you aren't asking for outside help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Remove the animated gif and the flicker stops.

Looking at the CSS, I noticed that the image was being resized for display.

I created a copy of the image using an online editor to the size that I needed.

Switching the animated gif to a version not requiring resizing solved the problem.

Comment: How do you know that the image in the question is resized?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's your CPU that can't handle the load? This could especially be caused on an older machine on a website running intensive javascript.

Comment: Nope, not it.  Machine is just fine.  I work at a gaming company, so the one thing they don't cheap on is CPU, RAM and Video cards :)

Comment: Please provide some html so that we at least have the idea of how you are placing it.

Answer (score 0):

> Suffice it to say that we have an
>   animated gif absolutely positioned. it
>   is ~ 600 x 400. it sits beneath
>   another abs. positioned div which
>   provides a transparency layer. Finally
>   the form itself is abs. positioned
>   over that.

```
<style type="text/css">
#img {
    position: absolute;
}
#dv {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid Black;
    height: 450px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
}
#frm {
    left: 170px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
</style>
<img src="http://vulcan.wr.usgs.gov/Imgs/Video/MSH/MSH06/MSH06_MOVIE_before_after_from_brutus_10-21_and_10-22-06_animated.gif" id="img">
<div id="dv">
</div>
<form id="frm">
<input type="text">
</form>
```

I tried to replicate what you described as closely as possible. I loaded the above into IE 6, 7 and 8 and was unable to see any flickering cursor problems.

Given that I can come up with an implementation that does not exhibit the issue, there does not seem to be any general *animated-gif-causes-input-cursor-flickering* bug in IE 7 and something in your specific markup and CSS is exposing the problem in that browser.

> Take away the gif, and the problem
>   goes away.
>
> knowing for a fact that the animated
>   gif is the reason for the screen draw
>   is the result of a successful debug.

Certainly adding the animated gif is the final piece of the puzzle leading to what you are seeing. But as I've demonstrated, you can have an absolutely positioned form over an absolutely positioned animated gif with a transparent div between them and the cursor does not flicker.

I think you are going to have to strip away what you are doing one layer at a time until you can determine specifically what it is in your markup or CSS that exposes the problem.

There is one other possibility, the flickering you are seeing may be an artifact of your video card and/or video driver. You might want to try viewing the page under IE 7 on a machine with completely different hardware to rule out this possibility.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but you are incorrect.  The animated gif you used in your example had a framerate that is to low.  To be clear:  I did not get a flicker with your example.  I modified your code, used my image, and the flicker is there.  I've edited my original post to reflect this.  I appreciate the attempt, but my problem persists, and the original analysis is still the best one.